# Listen to or hear a song?

Tags: word-usage

What sounds natural in the sentences below:

> Hey! Did you "listen to/hear" this song?
>
> Yes I "listened to/heard" it.
>
> Have you "listened to/heard" this song before?
>
> Yes I have "listened to/heard" this song before.

What will be used in the sentences above "listen to/hear"?

Comment: I think both are correct. But "listen" is agentive and "hear" is non-agentive. So you listen to something on purpose but hear something by accident.

Comment: On purpose @user178049

Answer (score 0):

'***Hearing***’ is an event;
 it is something which happens to us as a natural process.

‘***Listening***’ is an action; it is something we do consciously.

Sometimes (as in your case) we can use either ***hear*** or ***listen*** ***to***, depending on whether we want to emphasise the event or the action:

- Did you hear this song on the radio yesterday?

Have you ever heard this song?

(emphasis on the *event*)

- Did you listen to this song on the radio yesterday?

Have you ever listened to this song?

(emphasis on the *action*)

You can read more [here](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/hear-or-listen-to).